# Priority field in CVE pages on http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-XXXX

Tags: security

On http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/ security patches for packages are announced and correlated with the corresponding CVE from Mitre.

I just wonder, how the "Priority" is set. For instance, the exploit in the jdk package has a cvss v2 base value of 10.0 (follow link to NVD [here](http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-2015-0469)), highest possible, but the priority from ubuntu view is only "medium", whereas [heartbleed](http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-2014-0160) with cvss v2 base of 5.0 got a priority of "high".

Is this priority field just a result of human investigation or do I mix anything?

Comment: There's also the consideration of installed base and usage. Bash is present on practically **every** Ubuntu installation  out there, is at the heart of an extremely large number of scripts, whereas Java ~ not so much. I'd any day grant a higher priority to a bash exploit than a Java exploit. (And to hear people speak of it, Java exploits pop up every now and then anyway.)

Comment: Well, java was only some example. Of course you are right. A heartbleed or shellshock is more important for server systems than a pure client based java exploit. Nevertheless, the pure technical cvss values say something different. So, the prio-field seems to be set by a human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the consideration of installed base and usage. Bash is present on practically every Ubuntu installation out there, is at the heart of an extremely large number of scripts, whereas Java ... not so much. I'd any day grant a higher priority to a bash exploit than a Java exploit. (And to hear people speak of it, Java exploits pop up every now and then anyway.)

---

The [Security Team Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam) links to the CVE Tracker's [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/annotate/head%3A/README), which describes the priorites:

```
negligible        Something that is technically a security problem, but is
                  only theoretical in nature, requires a very special
                  situation, has almost no install base, or does no real
                  damage.  These tend not to get backport from upstreams,
                  and will likely not be included in security updates unless
                  there is an easy fix and some other issue causes an update.

low               Something that is a security problem, but is hard to
                  exploit due to environment, requires a user-assisted
                  attack, a small install base, or does very little damage.
                  These tend to be included in security updates only when
                  higher priority issues require an update, or if many
                  low priority issues have built up.

medium            Something is a real security problem, and is exploitable
                  for many people.  Includes network daemon denial of service 
                  attacks, cross-site scripting, and gaining user privileges.
                  Updates should be made soon for this priority of issue.

high              A real problem, exploitable for many people in a default
                  installation.  Includes serious remote denial of services,
                  local root privilege escalations, or data loss.

critical          A world-burning problem, exploitable for nearly all people
                  in a default installation of Ubuntu.  Includes remote root
                  privilege escalations, or massive data loss.
```

In this case, Shellshock was a bug affecting a software that's part of the default installation - bash. Therefore, it's high priority.

As far as I can tell, the priority is set by people during [bug triaging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/BugTriage).